# Enable/disable vibration function in android?

Tags: android, service, vibration, android-vibration

I have implemented vibration using vibrator .In my application, when the user press the button, vibration works.For some users wont like vibration in app so i had a toggle button as vibration on/off.
i just need to know how to implement the  enable/disable the vibration function.
this is my vibrator class

```
      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  
     vib.vibrate(500);
      Toast.makeText(this, "vib started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use boolean flag to toggle

```
if(isVibrate){
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  
     vib.vibrate(500);
      Toast.makeText(this, "vib started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else{

// do nothing

}
```

Comment: You should also check the device audio status - don't vibrate if the user has their device on silent - AudioManager.getRingerMode() should return RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE or RINGER_MODE_NORMAL