# Enabling and disabling vibration in android programmatically

Tags: android

In one of my android apps, I need to enable or disable the vibration completely irrespective of the mode (i.e. silent or general or loud).

I am currently using the following code with the help of the **deprecated function 
setVibrateSetting**

// For turning on the vibration mode

```
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
```

// For turning off the vibration mode

```
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

But I am wondering if there is a clear way to do this.

And suggestions are most welcome :)

Regards,
Jujare

Comment: Have a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965586/android-setvibratesetting-deprecated

Comment: Google used deprecation here inappropriately because there is no other way to change system wide vibration settings

Comment: The word deprecation is always confusing for developers. Deprecation means there is a better way available rather than you can't use it!

Answer (score 5):

The deprecation text for [`setVibrateSetting()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setVibrateSetting%28int,%20int%29) says:

> This method should only be used by applications that replace the
>   platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony
>   application.

From what I understand, there is no other option to globally enable or disable vibration, so if you have an app such as a ring profile manager, you probably need to use it.

IMHO, Google used deprecation here inappropriately.

I use the following class to hide the deprecation in one "compat" class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
class AudioManagerCompat {
    final static int VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER = AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER;
    final static int VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION = AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_ON = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT;

    static int getVibrateSetting(AudioManager am, int vibrateType) {
        return am.getVibrateSetting(vibrateType);
    }

    static void setVibrateSetting(AudioManager am, int vibrateType, int vibrateSetting) {
        am.setVibrateSetting(vibrateType, vibrateSetting);
    }
}
```

Comment: `IMHO, Google used deprecation here inappropriately.` You are right because there is no other way to change system wide vibration settings. But the word `deprecation` is always confusing for developers. Deprecation means there is a better way available rather than you can't use it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        break;
    case 1:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        break;
    case 2:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
                AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
        break;
    case 3:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
                AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        break;
    }
```

setVibrateSetting works fine when I use my nexus s with Gingerbread and IceCreamSandwich, I develop it with ICS, however recently I found it doesn't work with Jelly Bean, and getVibrateSetting also doesn't work. Waiting for a better way~

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code lines:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

vibration.cancel();
```

Answer (score -3):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014005/enable-disable-vibration-function-in-android), i found that as the first google result. The code:

```
if(isVibrate){
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  
     vib.vibrate(500);
      Toast.makeText(this, "vib started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

else{

// do nothing

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, my question was to disable or enable the vibration on a system level. My question is not about how I can use the vibrator device.