# Android 5 Lollipop disable vibration globally

Tags: android, vibration

I am currently using the "deprecated" code in the example below to disable vibrations globally on the phones using my app, but so far I have discovered that it is no longer working in Android 5, but it had worked fine in Android 4 and below. There are many complains about Google taking the silent mode out but there must be a way how to disable vibration, I guess. But I couldn't find any other example in the documentation nor via google.

Any ideas pls help...

The example:
[Enabling and disabling vibration in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087322/enabling-and-disabling-vibration-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to fully disable vibrations at the moment in Lollipop is Silent Mode (which is completely different than what our old silent mode is). I hope this gets fixed, but there is no other way currently to disable it all.